Firebase RTDB: Query delay while local cache updating
I faced the issue with RTDB trying run a query: data comes with large delay. My steps are the following.

At first I set all my data would be cached, calling db.getReference("timeline").keepSynced(true). All my timeline data is about 40-50 MB. I also set Firebase SDK local cache size to max 100 MB, with this db.setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(104857600L)

Right after that I run a query to get timeline, see below. The very first query after app was installed goes pretty fast and takes about 2-5 sec. But the next time this query can take much more time, about 1-2 min or even more. Please take a look at log below.


Query:
Timber.d("getTrips getTimelineCloud $dayTag")
val ref = database.getReference("timeline/240416/trips")
ref.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    Timber.d("getTrips getTimelineCloud $dayTag result size = ${task.result.childrenCount}")
}

Data: I'm querying current date trips data located at timeline/240416/trips as shown below (approx 150KB)
{
  "405": {
    "finishStation": "Ettelbruck",
    "finishTime": 1712725980000,
    "startStation": "Rodange",
    "startTime": 1712721072000
  },
  "406": {
    "finishStation": "Ettelbruck",
    "finishTime": 1712729580000,
    "startStation": "Rodange",
    "startTime": 1712724672000
  },
  "407": {
    "finishStation": "Ettelbruck",
    "finishTime": 1712733180000,
    "startStation": "Rodange",
    "startTime": 1712728272000
  },
  // 800+ items below, it takes 150KB
}

Log:
18:40:12.548 TimelineManager            D  getTrips getTimelineCloud 240416
18:42:06.487 TimelineManager            D  getTrips getTimelineCloud 240416 result size = 1066


Keep in mind that 40-50MB of structured JSON data is quite a lot. The time to download it will depend on the network speed, and the time to process it will depends on the number of nodes in there. Speeding it up typically requires downloading less data or restructuring the data.

Can you edit your question to: 1) show a single code snippet that we can run that takes longer than you'd expect, and show how you measure that? 2) show a representative snippet of the JSON that is being loaded?

You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of your Firebase Database console. That will show us the actual structure, rather than just the top-level (as I said in my initial comment, the processing time will depend on the complexity of the structure - not just its serialized size). --- Please also include how you measure the performance (preferably in the code).

The first part of your question still speaks of loading 40-50MB. Can you update and then also show for the 130KB payload the output from Timber that shows how long it took? --- I'd recommend doing a reset too: remove the code that tries changes the cache size, and delete/reinstall the app (to delete the cache file from disk). With that, on a clean start - what logging output/timing do you get?

@FrankvanPuffelen I've updated the post, log data were added as you asked, pls take a look

Since you're calling keepSynced(true) on the entire timeline node, your local cache will contain all JSON data under that node. Given your indication of 40-50MB that's a boatload of child nodes. When you run a query against timeline, Firebase will first load all that data from the cache into memory, which takes an amount of time (and memory) that is linear to the number and size of the child nodes.

The Realtime Database's caching behavior was made/optimized for cases where you rerun the same queries while you are offline that you ran while online. Your use-case seems different: preloading data that you then want to query while offline. While everything may technically work, I doubt you'll every get satisfactory performance with this size of data. I recommend looking at a primarily local database instead.

Since you're calling keepSynced(true) on the entire timeline node, your local cache will contain all JSON data under that node. Given your indication of 40-50MB that's a boatload of child nodes.
When you run a query against timeline, Firebase will first load all that data from the cache into memory, which takes an amount of time (and memory) that is linear to the number and size of the child nodes at the path/in the cache.
The Realtime Database's caching behavior was made/optimized for cases where you rerun the same queries while you are offline that you ran while online. Your use-case seems different: you're preloading data that you then want to query while offline. While everything may technically work, I doubt you'll every get satisfactory performance with this size of data.
I recommend looking at a primarily local database instead. Firestore is better suited to this type of usage, as it's local cache is backed by an actual database, is indexed and not as memory dependent. For full control of your scalability though, consider whether you should use a local-first/local-only database and only use Firebase for syncing the data from the cloud DB to the device (if even that).

I've removed all timeline caching db.getReference("timeline").keepSynced(true) with set to cache trips separately db.getReference("timeline/240416/trips").keepSynced(true). It works good, but the case when I switch the device from offline to online: then getting trips takes 2-3+ minutes and this the issue.

Sometimes this issue can be reproduce even with using addListenerForSingleValueEvent, when I using it instead of get. It looks like the bug we were found recently https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/5771

My log of getting trips (130KB) for case when I switch device from offline to online using addListenerForSingleValueEvent:
17:03:37.113 TimelineManager            D  getTrips start dayTag = 240417
17:05:06.566 TimelineManager            D  getTrips getTimelineCloud 240417 result size = 1064

On #5771: I'm the one who reported that, but it's different from your use-case. Yours is slow when data is present in the cache, where there the listeners never resolved when data is not present. --- For you:I suspect the time does not go so much into the actual returning of the data, but in loading the 40-50MB of JSON from the local cache. As said in my answer, this precaching of much data to then load a subset of it is a use-case that the RTDB SDK wasn't made for. If this is a required use-case, I recommend looking at another product that supports it (better).

I made more clear and detailed post about this issue, using a lightweight cloud data to cache https://stackoverflow.com/q/78349763/1621111
