Firebase RTDB: Getting data issue using persistence mode
This post aims to clarify the issue with getting data usign persistence mode. Shortly, Android Firebase RTDB getters works not correctly, when my app goes from offline to online: getting data takes too long (1-2+ minutes), or even longer (sometime callback doesn't come at all). Lib version: firebase-bom: 29.0.0.
Test preconditions. My RTDB stores trips list of about 1000 nodes, placed to timeline/240418/trips. Each trip node is pretty lightweight (see below) and full the list takes about 130-150KB. So I need to get the trips list online and offline. Android app was reinstalled to avoid old cache presence.
"405": {
    "finishStation": "Ettelbruck",
    "finishTime": 1712725980000,
    "startStation": "Rodange",
    "startTime": 1712721072000
  }

All test queries will call by this code:
Timber.d("getTrips 240418")
val ref = database.getReference("timeline/240418/trips")
ref.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    Timber.d("getTrips 240418 result size = ${task.result.childrenCount}")
}

Read when persistence mode off and keepSynced is never called. This works online as expected. When offline, listener may comes with error, but sometimes it doesn't comes at all. Firebase team set bug #5771 for this. Discussion of the issue.
db.setPersistenceEnabled(false)

Read when persistence mode on, and trips list is cached. Here sometimes I get an issue: when I switch my device from offline to online and right after that make the query, it takes too long and listener may fire in 1-2+ minutes. This issue comes not often, so I can't catch it every time. The issue comes also with using ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent() instead of ref.get(). I'm looking for a workaround of this issue. Upd: the issue also may come when I start my app from scratch and then trying to get trips.
db.setPersistenceEnabled(true)
db.getReference("timeline/240418/trips").keepSynced(true)

Log:
16:59:11.725 TimelineManager            D  getTrips 240418
17:00:56.391 TimelineManager            D  getTrips 240418 result size = 1021

